# A factory produces 100 unit of a certain product and 5 of them are defective.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A factory produces 100 unit of a certain product and 5 of them are defective. If 3 units are picked at random then what is the probability that none of them are defective?

Do I just use combination and solve this: is it 95 C 3 / 100 C 3?

Comment: Yes. it's true.

Comment: More formally, from hypergeometric distribution: $\frac{{95\choose 3}{5 \choose 0}}{{100\choose 3}}.$